# Chrome application shortcuts open small window

Tags: unity, compiz, google-chrome

I have created a bunch of chrome application shortcuts - gmail, tweetdeck, etc. They all launch in tiny windows in the upper left of the screen (see screenshot). It's easy enough to resize/maximize them - but I would like to know what controls their placement and sizing, and then be able to fix it? I've tried using compiz to maximize the window on launch but it doesn't work (compiz works fine for selecting which workspace to place it on, just not resizing). I expect there must be a setting somewhere that dictates this - any ideas?

[image: Small Window]

Comment: It can easily be fixed with the help (use) of `wmctrl` in your command to open the shortcut command, but the question is what causes it. What is the command? And a silly question, but does it persist after a log out/in?

Comment: wmctrl sounds like a good fix. The command is:

Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=http://feedly.com/i/my

But I do see another property in the launcher file that may be relevant:
StartupWMClass=feedly.com__i_my

And yes, it persists.

Answer (score 0):

Just to see what happened, I created some webapp- launchers. What you describe occurred to me as well, but in an unpredictable way; sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't.

#### Opening a webapp window with a pre defined size

To guarantee that a *newly created window* of a certain application has a certain size, turned out to be a bit more complicated than I anticipated. I think however that the solution below works elegantly.

#### What it does and how to use

The solution below redirects the command to run the webapp to a script. The scripts runs the command, waits for the corresponding window to appear (waiting for the `pid` of `chrome` to produce a new window) and resizes it to the size that you define.

*In practice:*

Looking inside the webapp's `.desktop` file, you see in the `Exec=` line (as you mentioned) a command, looking like:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=feedly.com/i/my
```

After you made the setup below, all you need to do is to replace the command in this (or any other webapps-) file to:

```
Exec=run_maximized "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=feedly.com/i/my" 100 100
```

The last to figures in the command are the horizontal/vertical sizes of the window (in %, related to the screen size)

#### The setup

1. The script uses both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `run_maximized` (no extension) in `~/bin`. Create the directory if it does not exist. Make the script executable.
3. If you just created the directory `~/bin`, either log out/in or run

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```
4. In the webapp's `.desktop` file, replace the command in the `Exec=` line:

   ```
   Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=feedly.com/i/my
   ```

   to:

   ```
   Exec=run_maximized "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --app=feedly.com/i/my" 100 100
   ```

   Mind the quotes, and don't forget the horizontal/vertical size of the window

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import time
import sys

user = getpass.getuser()
get = lambda x: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", x]).decode("utf-8")
ws1 = get("wmctrl -lp"); t = 0
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", sys.argv[1]])

while t < 30:      
    ws2 = [w.split()[0:3] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if not w in ws1]
    procs = [[(p, w[0]) for p in get("ps -u "+user).splitlines() \
              if "chrome" in p and w[2] in p] for w in ws2]
    if len(procs) > 0:
        command = "xdotool windowsize "+procs[0][0][1]+" "+sys.argv[2]+"% "+sys.argv[3]+"%"
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])
        break
    time.sleep(0.5)
    t = t+1
```

#### Notes

- I used `xdotool` to resize the window. It could also be done with `wmctrl`, but the `maximize` command of `wmctrl` has some side effects that `xdotool` does not have.
- With a minor change of the script, it can be made usable to run windows of a predefined size (or position) of any application. Could be usefull in quicklists for example, to create multiple windows in a predefined layout.